# Why can I not see a data value when hovering over a point on the radar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a Radar Chart using ChartJS as follows:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="radarChartTest" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
    radarChartTest(["A", "B", "C", "D"], [5, 10, 15, 20], document.getElementById("radarChartTest"));
</script>
```

JS:

```
function radarChartTest(categories, totals, chartToPopulate) {
    var chartDisplay = chartToPopulate;
    var newChart = new Chart(chartDisplay, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
            labels: categories,
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: totals,
                    label: "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qo25vxu3/1/)

The chart draws and populates fine. However, when I hover over a radar point, it does not display the value:

[image: broken chart]

There should be a number after `test:`.

I am expecting something similar to this:

[image: working radar chart]

Am I missing an attribute or something? I have checked the documentation but could not spot anything for it. I have also compared my code to where I found ([a working example](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/#4-radar-chart)), but could not spot anything there either.

Comment: Try putting the slimmed down code (including HTML) and how the function is being called in jsFiddle so it can be tested [mcve]

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you for the suggestion...it is done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the that version (2.8.0) of Chart.js ([Values on Tooltip of Radar Chart is not shown](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6188)).

You can fix it by upgrading to 2.9.0.

[Updated working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/hmpwsnuz/) with version 2.9.0

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.0"> </script>
```

Comment: I have since updated the fiddle and can see it is no longer functioning

Comment: Yup, thats because your updated fiddle uses version 2.8.0. Try 2.7.3.

Comment: I see now. I'm surprised I could not find this bug documentation when searching.

Comment: fix for this was released - v2.9.0

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell I had the same problem a while ago, maybe, because I'll need to research a little more about this issue, the problem is due to a previous version of Chart.js. In any case here is a `CodePen` with a solution to your problem [RadarChart Example](https://codepen.io/sigfriedCub/pen/zXpmBO). Hope this helps. Cheers, sigfried.

**UPDATE**
Since this is not only about the answers here is the link from the documentation of Chart.js that I used to solve the tooltips issue [Label Callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to re-create the problem you have but it looks all good to me.(A number after "total")

Since you only post part of your code, I am not sure where you are confused.
  So I attached the full code I created here. Compare it to your code and let me know if you still can't generate the figure you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript chart</h2>

<p>Radar Chart Demo </p>

<canvas id="radar-chart" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>

function radarChart(categories, totals, averages, chartToPopulate, chartTitle) {
var chartDisplay = chartToPopulate;
var newChart = new Chart(chartDisplay, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: categories,
        datasets: [
            {
                data: averages,
                pointBackgroundColor: ["rgba(199,54,54,1)", "rgba(199,54,122,1)", "rgba(199,54,154,1)", "rgba(146,54,199,1)", "rgba(69,54,199,1)", "rgba(54,103,199,1)", "rgba(54,165,199,1)", "rgba(54,199,180,1)"],
                pointBorderColor: ["rgba(199,54,54,1)", "rgba(199,54,122,1)", "rgba(199,54,154,1)", "rgba(146,54,199,1)", "rgba(69,54,199,1)", "rgba(54,103,199,1)", "rgba(54,165,199,1)", "rgba(54,199,180,1)"],
                pointRadius: 15,
                pointStyle: "cross",
                pointHoverRadius: 25,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
                pointRotation: 45,
                pointBorderWidth: 1.2,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(61,49,225,0.5)",
                borderColor: "rgba(61,49,225,1)",
                label: "Averages",
                fill: true
            },
            {
                data: totals,
                pointBackgroundColor: ["rgba(199,54,54,1)", "rgba(199,54,122,1)", "rgba(199,54,154,1)", "rgba(146,54,199,1)", "rgba(69,54,199,1)", "rgba(54,103,199,1)", "rgba(54,165,199,1)", "rgba(54,199,180,1)"],
                pointBorderColor: ["rgba(199,54,54,1)", "rgba(199,54,122,1)", "rgba(199,54,154,1)", "rgba(146,54,199,1)", "rgba(69,54,199,1)", "rgba(54,103,199,1)", "rgba(54,165,199,1)", "rgba(54,199,180,1)"],
                pointRadius: 15,
                pointStyle: "cross",
                pointHoverRadius: 25,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
                pointRotation: 45,
                pointBorderWidth: 1.2,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(225,49,52,0.35)",
                borderColor: "rgba(225,49,52,1)",
                label: "Totals",
                fill: true
        },                 
        ]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRation: false,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: chartTitle,
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
})
return chartDisplay;
}


var Chart = radarChart(["1","2","3","4"], [100,200,300,400], [10,20,30,40], 
document.getElementById("radar-chart"), "TEST")

document.getElementById("radar-chart").innerHTML = Chart;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the version 2.8, and i got the same problem, to fix

```
tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ' : ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                    }
                }
            }
```

See the issue

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6188#issuecomment-497251833